# Displaying fields in a unique php page for each row in myql Wordpress Database

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress

I have a table called "races" in my Wordpress database.

[image]

**main.php**
my events page displays all of my races inside the table "races" - everything works fine here

```
<?php
global $wpdb;
$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "races";
$result = $wpdb->get_results ( "SELECT * FROM races ORDER BY date_start LIMIT 4" );?>
<div class="events-schedule">
<?php
foreach ( $result as $race )   {

    $title = $race->title;
    $raceid = $race->race_id;
    $location = $race->venue;
    $icon = $race->race_icon;
   ?>

    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="small-12 medium-4 columns event-icon text-center">
                    <img src="<?php echo $icon; ?>">
            </div>
            <div class="small-12 medium-8 columns text-center">
                <?php echo $id; ?>
                    <h3 class="tagline location"><?php echo $location; ?> </h3>
                    <h2><?php echo $title; ?></h2>

                    <div><a class="btn yellow" href="/test/?id=<?php echo $id; ?>">Apply Now</a></div>
                </div>
            </div>

        <?php
    echo '</div>';

 }  ?>
 </div> <?php
?>
```

**test.php** I am trying to display the other fields on this individual page when you go to http://mywebsite.com/test/?id=64
All I am getting is the number "64" which is fine because that is the correct ID!
I am trying to retrieve the other fields, such as the title, venue, etc.. but not working. Am I missing something?

Thank you in advance.

```
<?php
$id = $_GET['id']; 

echo $id;

 $result = $wpdb->get_results ( "SELECT * FROM races WHERE id='$id'" );

foreach ($result as $race) {

$title = $race->title;
   echo $title;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably not getting back any results, so the for loop never executes. Are you sure that id 64 actually exists?

Also it is a terrible practice to put variables from the URL directly in the query. I can inject SQL into your system as easily as appending it to the URL. You need to sanitize your input to protect yourself from attackers.

After seeing your db schema it looks like the id field is actually named race_id. So your query should be like this:
`$wpdb->get_results ( "SELECT * FROM races WHERE race_id='$id'" );`

Comment: Thank you, How do I do this?

Comment: I am getting results on the main.php page, as well as the other fields.

Comment: You have to bind the variables. See the syntax they use here: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/prepare/

Comment: Ok, what about the actual problem I have which is displaying the values on the individual test.php page?

Comment: Like I said, id 64 probably does not exist. Have you confirmed that it does exist?

Comment: It does, it is listed on the main.php page with the id 64. When I go to http://mywebsite.com/test/?id=64 , the echo $id displays 64, does that mean it exists?

Comment: No it displays because you are grabbing it from the $_GET variable and then echoing it. That has nothing to do with the query.

Comment: I see, so how can I display the values then?

Comment: Please put var_dump($result); so that we can see what you are actually getting back from the database.

Comment: $result = $wpdb->get_results ( "SELECT * FROM races WHERE id='$id'" );
var_dump($result);  this outputs array(0) { }

Comment: You have to add: global $wpdb;

Comment: gives same output of array(0) { }

Comment: Are you just hitting test.php? You have to incorporate that into Wordpress so that you have access to the Wordpress database. That response means you are not getting back any results so please investigate your query.

Comment: Also be sure that error reporting is turned on:
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

Comment: I am going to this link http://mywebsite.com/test/?id=64  to see if it works. This is what may be wrong?  $result = $wpdb->get_results ( "SELECT * FROM races WHERE id='$id'" );

Comment: I took off ----  WHERE id='$id'  ---- from the query and they all display now... so I must be not setting the id correctly to the query?

Comment: It really seems like that id does not exist. Where in main.php is $id defined? I don't even see where you are assigning anything to that variable.

Comment: I've added a screenshot of my db so you can take a look. It is also called race_id on the db, not sure if that makes a difference?

Comment: Yes that makes a difference!! id is not the same as race_id. That's why it is not working.

Comment: Looks like all I had to do was change WHERE id='$id' to WHERE race_id='$id'  and now it works. Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score -1):

Firstly remove single quote from id and make your query like this

```
$wpdb->get_results ( "SELECT * FROM races WHERE race_id=$id" );
```

for display all fields do this

```
foreach($result as $race){
  echo $title = $race->title;
  echo $field_1= $race->field_1;
  echo $field_2= $race->field_2;
  echo $field_3= $race->field_3;
}
```

Note:: put your fields in place of field_1,field_2,field_3